# Xcode 3.2.3 - No SDK 3.1.3

Tags: xcode, ios4

after having installed Xcode 3.2.3 with iPhone SDK 4 (Seed) on OSX 10.6 there is no SDK 3.1.3 more available. Is there any possibility to reactivate it?

BR

Sven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just leave the Base SDK on 4.0 and just change the iPhone OS Deployment Target to be 3.1.3 or whatever you need it to be.

Answer (score 8):

Do the following

- sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all (This will uninstall the current XCode installation)
- reboot
- Then install first old Xcode (3.2 final) in default folder (/Developer)
- Then install the new Xcode (3.2.3 GM) in other folder (/DeveloperBeta)
- This way you will have both. And can launch xcode from either /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app or /DeveloperBeta/Applications/Xcode.app

3.2.3 last beta did remove all other SDK's cause to many people tried publish Apps developed with the beta SDK, which will not be accepted and I guess that's still happening with the GM release.

Comment: Note: uninstall-devtools says to reboot after you install the old version.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install both in different folders. In iOS4 there is only SDK 3.2 and 4.0

Comment: As nicktmro mentioned, you can just change the iPhone OS Deployment Target to be 3.1.3 or whatever you need it to be.

You only need to install in separate directoires if you want to change your base sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with Toby, above... AFAI understand it, there's no longer any need to set your project's Base SDK to 3.x, simply use 4.x for that -- and then set your "deployment target" to whatever lowest version of the (device) OS you want to support for your app. HTH clarify... ;-) cheers.